# Jquery validation exactlength for two numbers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm using the validator plugin for a form.
I would use the method exactlength but with 2 numbers.
I would check that the field is either 11 or 10 characters.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || value.length == param;
}, jQuery.format("Please enter exactly {0} characters."));

$("#formtovalidate").validate({
 rules: {
  somefield: {
    exactlength: 10,
    exactlength: 11
  }
});
```

You can do it? How can I change the method to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass the same key twice like that, what you need to do is to pass it as an array

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("exactlength", function(value, element, param) {
  if (this.optional(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  if ($.isArray(param)) {
    return $.inArray(value.length, param) != -1;
  } else {
    return value.length == param;
  }
}, function(param, input) {
  return jQuery.validator.format("Please enter exactly " + ($.isArray(param) ? param.join() : param) + " characters.")
});

$("form").validate({
  debug: true,
  rules: {
    f1: {
      exactlength: [10, 11]
    },
    f2: {
      required: true,
      exactlength: 3
    }

  }
});

//
$('#save').click(function() {
  $('form').valid()
  return false;
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form>
  <div>
    <input name="f1" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input name="f2" />
  </div>
  <input id="save" type="button" value="save" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand why return this error: TypeError: a.validator.methods[d] is undefined

Comment: which is the version of validator used?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake!! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much!